# how shall I document the use of GET or POST in a controller method?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

I am searching for a best-practice-way to document my controller methods in php.
I was wondering how I should document my `POST` and `GET` requirements (I used `REQUEST` here to show I need it for both ways).

i.e. see this method:

```
public function login(){

    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
    $stay_loggedin = $_REQUEST['stay-loggedin'];

    $user = new usermodel();
    if ($user->login($username, $password, $stay_loggedin) ) return <something>;
    else return page_not_allowed;
}
```

It would be great if someone can tell me a way which is php-doc compatible...
I mean `@param` wouldn't be the right way, woudldn't it?

Shall I document the required usermodel class as well? And how?

thanks for your help

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121710/is-there-a-standard-for-documenting-get-post-parameters

Comment: no haven't seen that, but I surfed through all proposals ...

Comment: Well then pls do check that and this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269086/request-params-and-phpdoc

Comment: I don't get it, what is ment in in the first link you've posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For documenting GET/POST methods you can do like:

```
/**
 * Function to Login a user
 *
 * Requires $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password']
 * Optional $_REQUEST['stay-loggedin'] 
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function login(){

    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
    $stay_loggedin = $_REQUEST['stay-loggedin'];

    $user = new usermodel();
    if ($user->login($username, $password, $stay_loggedin) ) return ;
    else return page_not_allowed;
}
```

And you could document the usermodel class in usermodel class file itself.
Hope it helps

Comment: is there a plugin, which creates something like this in netbeans automaticly?